# What does this line of my Log mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

When sending a 'Post' request, I get this in my Log.
`Processing by SubgroupsController#add_timespan as */*`

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log tells the following:

**Controller_name#action_name as respond Mime Type**

Here is a list of default Rails Mime Types:

```
"*/*"                      => :all
"text/plain"               => :text
"text/html"                => :html 
"application/xhtml+xml"    => :html
"text/javascript"          => :js 
"application/javascript"   => :js 
"application/x-javascript" => :js 
"text/calendar"            => :ics   
"text/csv"                 => :csv   
"application/xml"          => :xml 
"text/xml"                 => :xml 
"application/x-xml"        => :xml 
"text/yaml"                => :yaml 
"application/x-yaml"       => :yaml 
"application/rss+xml"      => :rss   
"application/atom+xml"     => :atom  
"application/json"         => :json 
"text/x-json"              => :json
```

source (http://apidock.com/rails/Mime)

For more in-depth info (i know very little about this) check the docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) and this blog post (http://ryanbigg.com/2009/04/how-rails-works-2-mime-types-respond_to/)